# Permissions Scope

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, oauth

I've created a project which transfers data to SharePoint Online. OAuth is used for authorization/authentication.

At first I was using `AllSites.Manage` for my permissions scope, but due to some feedback I've received, I would like to restrict this further.

The project needs to be able to access one specific "target" Site and create, edit, delete Lists and Libraries.

I have tried `Web.Manage` but I'm now getting permissions errors:

```
"error": {
        "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
        }
    }
```

Any advice on what to use is greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it turns out I registered the Add-In at my top-level site, rather than the subsite I was attempting to transfer data to. This was the entire issue.